# convert VB.NET to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, iis-7.5

I'm trying to use web-based API. All I received from my client is this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim client = New Net.WebClient
    client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("apiUsername"), _
                                                    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("apiPassword"), _
                                                    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("apiDomain"))


    client.Headers(Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/json"
    Dim eventParam As New PlumbingLibrary.StreamGameParam With {.EnterpriseId = txtAuthorEID.Text,
                                                                 .HeaderText = TxtText.Text,
                                                                 .ImageUrl = txtURL.Text,
                                                                 .Title = txtPhotoURL.Text,
                                                                 .Description = txtAlbumURL.Text}

    Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim serializer As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(PlumbingLibrary.StreamGameParam))
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, eventParam)

    Dim data As Byte() = client.UploadData(PlubingAPI_URL, "POST", stream.ToArray())


    stream = New IO.MemoryStream(data)
    serializer = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(PlumbingLibrary.Activity))
    Dim returnActivity = TryCast(serializer.ReadObject(stream), PlumbingLibrary.Activity)

    End Sub
```

This is part of working VB desktop application that I'm supposed to use as a example.
Project I'm working on is solely web based though. All written in javascript/jquery.

I tried this:

```
 var username = "API-ID",
    password = "API-PASS",
    url = "API-URL";


 function make_basic_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}

var auth = make_basic_auth(username,password);

$.support.cors = true;

  $.ajax
      ({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({EnterpriseId: "the.id",
                              HeaderText: " ",
                              ImageUrl: " ",
                              Title: " ",
                              Description: " "
        }),
        beforeSend : function(req) {
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
        },
        success: function (){
            console.log('Success');
            $("body").append("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
```

I also tried all other ajax + cors variations.

e.g.:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', url, true);

      console.log(xhr);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PINGOTHER', 'pingpong');
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
```

but I'm getting 401 unautorized and No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. 
The login information I have work with the desktop app. I can also login directly thru http login in browser to the API url.

Does anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can get a bit tricky with cross-domain. If you are receiving data back from the client in json format (and it looks like you do), try to tell your script you are receiving jsonp data by adding this line in your request: dataType: "jsonp"

```
$.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: JSON.stringify({EnterpriseId: "the.id",
                          HeaderText: " ",
                          ImageUrl: " ",
                          Title: " ",
                          Description: " "
    }),
    beforeSend : function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
    },
    success: function (){
        console.log('Success');
        $("body").append("success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, err) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried what you sugested. but I'm getting header 405 Method Not Allowed. Here is Fiddler log: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21648471/Screenshot%202014-02-12%2009.11.42.png)

Comment: here are response headers: 
#1 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 15:10:07 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
Set-Cookie: BIGipServer*********.*******.**********.com=1017452298.47873.0000; expires=Wed, 12-Feb-2014 16:10:02 GMT; path=/
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAACAAAABgAGADgAAAAVgoni/9xgn2SE96IAAAAAAAAAAMYAxgA+AAAABgGxHQAAAA9EAEkAUgACAAYARABJAFIAAQASAFYAUgBUAFYAVwAyADQAOAA0AAQAKgBkAGkAcgAuAHMAdgBjAC4AYQBjAGMAZQBuAHQAdQByAGUALgBjAG8AbQADAD4AVgBSAFQAVgBXADIANAA4ADQALgBkAGkAcgAuAHMAdgBjAC4AYQBjAGMAZQBuAHQAdQByAGUALgBjAG8AbQAFACIAcwB2AGMALgBhAGMAYwBlAG4AdAB1AHIAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAcACAB+rj2EBCjPAQAAAAA=
Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 15:10:07 GMT
Content-Length: 341
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

Comment: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: private
Allow: POST
Content-Length: 1735
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 15:10:07 GMT

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong but it seems like it actually logs in correctly but than it doesn't like `jsonp` method for some reason.

Comment: ok, so it does not like jsonp, did you try changing jsonp to json? also, when there is any Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors require the provider to provide proper header information. If it still does not work then you may have to use a custom handler.

Comment: Yes I tried json and jsonp and xml etc. At the end I was able to post there via PHP's cURL => [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737702/convert-php-curl-call-to-javascript-ajax-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737702/convert-php-curl-call-to-javascript-ajax-call) I'm going to build simple proxy.php and relay the ajax call thru there. It's dirty but it'll work.